# How to change all zero permissions in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

One of my colleagues changed file permissions to all zero by mistake.

As a result, all root folders seem to be like this:

```
I have no name!@myserver:/$ ls -al
total 12900
drwxr-xr-x   28    0    0   4096 Sep 23 08:18 .
drwxr-xr-x   28    0    0   4096 Sep 23 08:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2    0    0   4096 Oct  1 09:21 bin
drwxr-xr-x    3    0    0   4096 Jul 17 07:16 boot
drwxr-xr-x  141    0    0   4096 Nov 11 09:21 etc
................................................
```

And files and folders under /etc seem to be like this:

```
.......................................
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sudoers
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sudoers.d
.......................................
```

I cannot change permissions with the `chmod` or `chown` commands because of a permission denied error.
Whenever I try to do something, the system returns the following error message.

```
sudo: unable to open /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

How can I resolve this issue? Should I re-install ubuntu?

Comment: boot system repair, either special distro or ubuntu install, then mount the affected partitions and use chmod, however it would be safer to just reinstall the system (backup /home first)

Comment: Off-topic, ask on http://askubuntu.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Boot your machine in single user mode, it will give you the option to drop to the root shell.
Try changing permissions with root privilege.

Use steps at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) link boot in single user mode.